Vite Suddenly start loading too slow and there are no errors either
I am working in a MERN app and suddenly my website starts loading too slow. The code is same and there are no error either. First I started seeing blank pages. I though the problem is with a specific components I was creating at that moment so I deleted those file but still same result. I restarted the server many time but same issue
Vite config file
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})


package.json
{
  "name": "essays-se",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "ldrs": "^1.0.1",
    "mdb-react-ui-kit": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "react-tabs": "^6.0.2",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}


Give me a suggestion how to troubleshoot this.

This might have to do with your hosting and has nothing at all to do with your code
